Setting up screen reader for dynamically loaded content
I have a form that contains a zipcode testbox. When I type in a zipcode in the textbox, it renders a dropdown with city suggestions (ex. 90005 should give a list of two cities). When I turn on the screen reader and type a zipcode in the textbox, it announces the zipcode but it doesn't automatically announce the city suggestions from the dropdown. I used aria-live to achieve this but it does not work. aria-label in ProgressIcon is not being announced either. This is what I have so far. CityError is being announced. However, ShowSelection, ProgressIcon, and DropdownOptions are not being announced.
<>
  <ProgressIcon
    isDisplay={showFetchProgress}
    aria-live={'assertive'}
    aria-label={'City and State are being fetched.'}
  >
    <LoadingIcon size={'small'} />
  </ProgressIcon>
  <CitySuggestionWrapper
    isOpen={showSuggestions}
    aria-live={'assertive'}
    error={error}
  >
    <DropdownOptionsWrapper
      aria-expanded={showSuggestions}
      error={error}
    >
      {cityStates &&
        cityStates.map((item: any) => {
          return (
            <DropdownOptions
              key={item.city}
              id={item.city}
              onMouseDown={() => selectItem(item, dispatch)}
            >
              <a
                role={'button'}
                tabIndex={0}
                onKeyDown={(event) => keyPressSelectItem(event, item)}
              >
                {displayCityAddress(item)}
              </a>
            </DropdownOptions>
          );
        })}
    </DropdownOptionsWrapper>
    {error && (
      <CityError
        data-test={DataTestAttributes.CITY_ERROR}
        role={'alert'}
        aria-live={'polite'}
      >
        {getCityValidationText(cityField)}
      </CityError>
    )}
  </CitySuggestionWrapper>
  <ShowSelection
    isShow={showAddress}
    aria-live={'assertive'}
  >
    {displayCityAddress(selectedCity)}
  </ShowSelection>
</>


The pattern you are trying to implement here is an Editable Combobox With List Autocomplete.
Any interactive component needs to communicate to the user (and the screen reader) how it’s going to work. For example that things are going to happen once you start typing.
This is achieved by providing ARIA roles like combobox and properties like aria-autocomplete="list".

aria-autocomplete property
Indicates whether inputting text could trigger display of one or more predictions of the user's intended value for a combobox, searchbox, or textbox and specifies how predictions would be presented if they were made.

Changes to ARIA states like aria-expanded get announced without being in a live region.
It is often used wrongly on the expanded contents as in the question, but intended to go on the triggering element, in this case the input.
It is unclear which roles, properties and states the component from the question uses. The necessary ones are all explained in the pattern’s description.
A Live Region is more intended for announcements that are not directly related to a user action. It is not intended or able to manage expectations about a component’s behaviour. Its abilities to announce state changes of included components.
